# PHP print text randomly once inside a loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have data selected from database in object format. I want to loop it but I also include text randomly to the display. How to add that text to a random place in object? or how to print it randomly once inside the loop?

> //Object data
>
> $obj = (object) [
>
> ```
> '0' => ['name' => 'Banana'],
>
> '1' => ['name' => 'Potato'],
>
> '2' => ['name' => 'Mango']
> ```
>
> ];
>
> //addition text will be displayed
>
> $text = 'My random text';
>
> foreach($obj as $d) {
>
> ```
>  echo $d->name;
> ```
>
> }

**Result can be**

- Banana
- Potato
- My random text
- Mango

**Or**

- My random text
- Banana
- Potato
- Mango

**Or**

- Banana
- My random text
- Potato
- Mango

...

Comment: So you want to write a PHP code that will print a random line from your database?

Comment: I'm sorry for lack information question. I have updated the question. Please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the a random position index from your object data like this.

```
$randPos = rand(0, count($obj)-1);
```

And put your random text right after this random index of object data while accessing it through look.

```
//addition text will be displayed

$text = 'My random text';

foreach($obj as $k => $d) {
   echo $d->name; 
   if($k == $randPos) echo $text;
}
```

*Hope this will help to solve your query !!*

Answer (score 1):

I would use a random number. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

```
$rand = rand(0, count($yourArray));
```

Then within your array loop, test the key value of the given item compared to your random number if it matches, echo your text.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a way of determining how many arrays are stored in your Object?

If so, generate a random number between 0 and `$numArraysInObject` - 1 and use a good ol' `for ($i = 0; $i < $numArraysInObject; $i++)`. When `$i` matches `$numArraysInObject`, print your random text.

```
$printTime = rand(0, $numArraysInObject);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numArraysInObject; $i++) {
    if ($i == $printTime)
        echo "My random text";
    echo $d -> name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this ..

```
foreach($obj as $d) {

 $d->name = $d->name . " " . $text;  // This concates the text.
 echo $d->name;
```

}